# Unable to Draw Chart using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, chart.js

I have previously had successfully drawn a simple line graph using ChartJS (by referring an online example) and pulling the required data from a MySQL DB. The previous had only one line in the graph as I pulled in only one field from the table (write speed).

Now I have updated it to pull three fields (test_id, write_speed, read_speed) from the DB and display two linegraphs within the chart. But now it does not work.

Being quite new to JavaScript, I'm unable to comprehend where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code pulling in the  data from the DB:

```
<?php
/**
 * filename: data.php
 */

//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'simpletest');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = "SELECT test_id, read_speed, write_speed FROM log2 ORDER BY test_id ASC";

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
  // Nope
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . $link->error . "n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die( $message );
}

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}


//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

The following is the HTML file calling in the scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Tesults New</title>
        <style>
            .chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chart-container">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/linegraph.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is the Chart Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * call the data.php file to fetch the result from db table.
     */
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/test/chartjs2/api/data.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);

            var testid = [];
            var readspeed = [];
            var writespeed = [];

            for (var i in data) 
            {
                testid.push("TestID " + data[i].test_id);
                readspeed.push(data[i].read_speed);
                writespeed.push(data[i].write_speed);
            }

            //get canvas

            var chartdata = {
                labels : testid,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label : "Read Speed in Gbps",
                        data : readspeed,
                        backgroundColor : "blue",
                        borderColor : "lightblue",
                        fill : false,
                        lineTension : 0,
                        pointRadius : 5
                    }

                    {
                        label : "Write Speed in Mbps",
                        data : writespeed,
                        backgroundColor : "blue",
                        borderColor : "darkblue",
                        fill : false,
                        lineTension : 0,
                        pointRadius : 5
                    }
                ]
            };

            var options = {
                title : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "top",
                    text : "New Test Results",
                    fontSize : 18,
                    fontColor : "#111"
                },
                legend : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "bottom"
                }
            };

            if (chart) {
                chart.destroy();
            }

            //var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
            var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
                type : "line",
                data : chartdata,
                options : options
            } );

        },
        error : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

I could be committing a really foolish mistake that might be completely eluding me, so please do point out if indeed have done something silly.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try to see in the console (F12 for dev tools, console tab) what the output of your script is. Add `debugger;` statement in your script. When you have the devtools open it will pause on that line and you can inspect the data to make sure it's correct.

Comment: I believe you are destroying the chart before declaration that might be causing error.

Comment: Updated my answer; it's either the syntax error,  wrong chartjs version (without bundle) or non valid json. I'd advice you to use chrome dev tools to see what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
    {
        label : "Write Speed in Mbps",
```

should be (add comma):

```
    ,{
        label : "Write Speed in Mbps",
```

Please check your console output and maybe use vscode or atom to edit your JavaScript code as the editor would have told you about the syntax error as well.

Make sure you use a recent version of chart.js (2.7.0 bundled up or with dependencies).

I cannot reproduce the error with fixed data so it is either a syntax error in your code, wrong json sent by php or wrong version of chart.js

```js
var testid = [1,2,3,4,5];
var readspeed = [6,7,8,9,10];
var writespeed = [4,5,6,7,8];

var chartdata = {
    labels : testid,
    datasets : [
        {
            label : "Read Speed in Gbps",
            data : readspeed,
            backgroundColor : "blue",
            borderColor : "lightblue",
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 5
        }

        ,{
            label : "Write Speed in Mbps",
            data : writespeed,
            backgroundColor : "blue",
            borderColor : "darkblue",
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 5
        }
    ]
};

var options = {
    title : {
        display : true,
        position : "top",
        text : "New Test Results",
        fontSize : 18,
        fontColor : "#111"
    },
    legend : {
        display : true,
        position : "bottom"
    }
};

if (chart) {
    chart.destroy();
}
var ctx = $('#mycanvas');
var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
    type : "line",
    data : chartdata,
    options : options
});
```

```html
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your suggestion did help. I went into Developer Tools and turns out the canvas declaration was a mismatch as that defined in the base HTML file. Had another silly syntax error as you pointed out: the missing comma (which sent me quite into a coma). Fixed them and they worked as expected. Thank you. :)